# Formula bar values excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have value in cells 10.0 but in the formula bar is 10 so if I copy
The value to another cell like
Range(”a1”)= Range(”b1”) I got 10 instead 10.0
Or I copy to another workbook
For display value work good but for formula bar no
I used number format did not work so if you can help me
Excel vba
Thank’s

Comment: Make sure your cells are formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeeped, Gosh you're not wrong.  Not sure what I was thinking there.

```
Range("a1") = Range("b1")
Range("a1").NumberFormat = "#0.0"
```

Comment: Thank’s very mush

Comment: The code work but My Question is , If I did import the data to ASP.net does the ASP take the Value of the cell or the value of the formula bar. I did not know anything about ASP.NET